# XML Content error in external subset / Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, dtd

I have XML with external DTD:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE autobazar SYSTEM "autobazar.dtd">
<autobazar>
    <auta>
        <auto id="1">
            <znacka>Chevrolet</znacka>
            <model>Camaro</model>
            <barva>Zluta</barva>
            <rok>2003</rok>
            <vin>YFA205AF7780R</vin>
            <prodejce>1</prodejce>
        </auto>

        <auto id="2">
            <znacka>Opel</znacka>
            <model>Manta</model>
            <barva>Cerna</barva>
            <rok>1895</rok>
            <vin>YFA404AE67POL</vin>
            <prodejce>1</prodejce>
        </auto>
    </auta>

    <prodejci>
        <prodejce id="1">
            <jmeno>Milan</jmeno>
            <prijmeni>Soustal</prijmeni>
            <provize>5%</provize>
        </prodejce>
    </prodejci>
</autobazar>
```

DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT autobazar (auta*,prodejci+)>
<!ELEMENT auta (auto*)>
<!ELEMENT auto (znacka, model, barva, rok, vin, prodejce+)>
<!ELEMENT prodejci (prodejce+)>
<!ELEMENT prodejce (jmeno, prijmeni, provize)>
<!ELEMENT znacka (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT barva (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rok (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT vin (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT jmeno (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prijmeni (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT provize (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST auto ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST prodejce ID #REQUIRED>
```

Im getting Content error  in external subset when i try to validate XML and Extra content at the end of the document error when validating DTD.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Your DTD is incorrect because you didn't specify the name of the attributes:

```
<!ATTLIST auto     ???? ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST prodejce ???? ID #REQUIRED>
```

The syntax for declaring attributes required that you provide the attribute name:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-value>
```

You can fix that by adding the name (`id` from your code):

```
<!ATTLIST auto     id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST prodejce id ID #REQUIRED>
```

<strike>XML will probably validate now with the corrected DTD.</strike>

**EDIT**: There are some other problems which you have to fix so the document validates. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, so I might make assumptions which might not be correct, based on what you expect:

1) Since `id` is declared as type `ID`, it not only can't occur more than once in the file, but it also can't start with a number. You have two options: a) if it's not really an `ID` (doesn't have to be unique), you can declare it as `NMTOKEN`:

```
<!ATTLIST auto     id NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```

b) if it *is* an `ID`, and has to be unique, you can append a letter or an underscore to it in your XML instance:

```
<auto id="c1">
...
```

2) Second you have `<prodejce>` with an `ID` which is the same as the first `auto`. Suppose we already corrected the `ID`s and they are no longer `1` but `c1`. It still won't work because `ID`s have to be unique in the document. Perhaps what you want is not an `ID`, but an `IDREF`, to associate `auto` with `prodecje`. In that case, you could do something like:

```
<!ATTLIST prodejce ref IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

and use `ref` in your XML to create the association:

```
<prodejce ref="c1">
```

3) But now it still fails, because the `ref` attribute is declared as `#REQUIRED` and there are two `prodejce` elements, inside `auto` which do not have the attribute. Perhaps it shouldn't  be `#REQUIRED` but `#IMPLIED`? You can remove this error either way: declaring it `#IMPLIED` or adding the missing attribute, but I'm guessing that's not exactly what you want to do, because there is a

4) Fourth problem! The element `prodejce` which declares as valid content `(jmeno, prijmeni, provize)`:

```
<!ELEMENT prodejce (jmeno, prijmeni, provize)>
```

That means it **must** contain those elements, in that order, one of each, and nothing else. In your XML document you have:

```
<prodejce>1</prodejce>
```

Which is illegal according to your DTD. Your DTD gives you no choice but to place the entire node there:

```
<auto id="c2">
      <znacka>Opel</znacka>
      <model>Manta</model>
      <barva>Cerna</barva>
      <rok>1895</rok>
      <vin>YFA404AE67POL</vin>
      <prodejce ref="c1">
           <jmeno>Milan</jmeno>
           <prijmeni>Soustal</prijmeni>
           <provize>5%</provize>
      </prodejce>
 </auto>
```

Should it be there? Does that make sense? If you don't want it there, you can make it optional in your DTD, changing the `+`:

```
<!ELEMENT auto (znacka, model, barva, rok, vin, prodejce+)>
```

for a `*`

```
<!ELEMENT auto (znacka, model, barva, rok, vin, prodejce*)>
```

but that also depends on your constraints. You are the one who knows if this is OK or not. Is it? I am guessing that you want to make an external reference to `prodejce` (since you were defining IDs in the first place). It it's that you should remove it from the content list of `auto`:

```
<!ELEMENT auto (znacka, model, barva, rok, vin)>
```

since now you will use `ID` and `IDREF` to associate `auto` to `prodejce`.

If I am right, now you could have an instance like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE autobazar SYSTEM "autobazar.dtd">
<autobazar>
    <auta>
        <auto id="c1">
            <znacka>Chevrolet</znacka>
            <model>Camaro</model>
            <barva>Zluta</barva>
            <rok>2003</rok>
            <vin>YFA205AF7780R</vin>
        </auto>

        <auto id="c2">
            <znacka>Opel</znacka>
            <model>Manta</model>
            <barva>Cerna</barva>
            <rok>1895</rok>
            <vin>YFA404AE67POL</vin>
        </auto>
    </auta>

    <prodejci>
        <prodejce ref="c1">
            <jmeno>Milan</jmeno>
            <prijmeni>Soustal</prijmeni>
            <provize>5%</provize>
        </prodejce>
    </prodejci>
</autobazar>
```

which would be valid according to this DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT autobazar (auta*,prodejci+)>
<!ELEMENT auta (auto*)>
<!ELEMENT auto (znacka, model, barva, rok, vin)>
<!ELEMENT prodejci (prodejce+)>
<!ELEMENT prodejce (jmeno, prijmeni, provize)>
<!ELEMENT znacka (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT barva (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rok (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT vin (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT jmeno (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prijmeni (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT provize (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST auto     id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST prodejce ref IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: unfortunetly, it didnt help :/ still the same error, but thanks for answer!

Comment: That correction will fix the DTD. But the file has another problem: since you declared the attribute type as `ID`, its value can't start with a number. It will work if your ID starts with a letter, for example: C1, C2, etc.

Comment: And if you declare the type as ID `prodejce` can't have the same ID as `auto`. Perhaps what you want is to declare an `IDREF` for `prodejce`. It will also fail because in some places you have `prodejce` without the `id` attribute, which is marked as `#REQUIRED`.

Comment: I edited the answer and made some assumptions. It may not be exactly what you want, but it might lead you in the right direction. Also, look for a good tutorial on DTD and XML. It will make things easier.